# IPython Notebook: Plotting with LaTeX?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Displaying lines of LaTeX in IPython Notebook has been answered previously, but how do you, for example, label the axis of a plot with a LaTeX string when plotting in IPython Notebook?

Comment: how did you install tex?  Was it perhaps BasicTex from MacTex?

Answer (score 9):

It works the same in IPython as it does in a stand-alone script. This example comes from [the docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif')
plt.figure(1, figsize = (6, 4))
ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7])
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0+0.01, 0.01)
s = cos(2*2*pi*t)+2
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{time (s)}')
plt.ylabel(r'\textit{voltage (mV)}', fontsize = 16)
plt.title(r"\TeX\ is Number $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-e^{i\pi}}{2^n}$!",
      fontsize = 16, color = 'r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('tex_demo')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Dropping that example code above into an IPy Notebook cell returns an error with content like: "RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:...! LaTeX Error: File `type1cm.sty' not found."  I understand that IPy Notebook handles LaTeX differently than IPython alone.

Comment: @user1988816   What OS are you using and how did you install LaTeX?

Comment: @user1988816: Within plots, the LaTeX is handled by matplotlib, not IPython. The IPython notebook has separate mechanisms to display LaTeX, but they're not used when you make a plot.

Comment: @user1988816 I bet you installed BasicTex from MacTex.  This doesn't have quite all the packages matplotlib needs to use tex (mostly a few fonts). You can install full MacTex to get them, or just add the missing ones, which I think would be: `tlmgr install dvipng helvetic palatino mathpazo type1cm`

Comment: I uninstalled MacTeX and reinstalled the full 2012 version but still get the same message. @minrk how do you install the missing packages you mentioned? I've seen elsewhere in the forums that texlive-latex-extra from MacPorts has the missing files but I couldn't find installation instructions for this either. Using Mountain Lion and MacTex 2012.

Comment: @user1988816 the command I pasted *is* how you install them.  `tlmgr` is a package manager for texlive packages.

Comment: the notebook handles latex display using mathjax which is already included in the web interface. there is no need for any latex engine.

ipthon qtconsole needs the latex engine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the problem posted in the comments: `! LaTeX Error: File 'type1cm.sty' not found.`

The issue was that my default tex command was not pointing to my up-to-date MacTex distribution, but rather to an old distribution of tex which I had installed using macports a few years back and which wasn't being updated since I had switched to using MacTex.

I diagnosed this by typing `which tex` on the command line and getting `/opt/local/bin/tex` which is not the default install location for MacTex.

The solution was that I had to edit my $PATH variable so that the right version of tex would get called by matplotlib.

I added `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH"` on the *last* line of my `~/.bash_profile`.

Now when I write `echo $PATH` on the command line I get:

`/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-darwin:blah:blah:blah...`

Don't forget to restart both your terminal and your jupyter server afterwards for the changes to take effect.